# Improve complexity of association list generation

Tags: haskell, time-complexity

I currently have a list of the form:

```
[(foo, bar), (foo, baz), (qux, quux)]
```

I would like to convert this into a list of the form:

```
[(foo, [bar, baz]), (qux, [quxx])]
```

In my actual use case, the list contains around 1 million of these tuples.

Currently, I'm solving this in the following way, which, while entirely pure and free of side-effects, also is (as I understand it) `O(n^2)`:

```
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as M
foo xs = M.fromListWith (++) $ xs
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fromListWith` algorithm [has an `O(n*log n)` time complexity](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.5.1/docs/Data-HashMap-Strict.html). This is the best you can get with no other constraints. The idea is that you need to traverse the list (`O(n)`) and foreach element insert (and check for duplicates) the key in the hash (`O(log(n))`).

With other constraints and with more space complexity you might be able to achieve a linear complexity. For example if the range of the keys is "compact" and the keys are integers, then you can use a vector/array and maybe pay more in terms of space, but get a `O(1)` lookup and insertion.

Comment: Hm, indeed. I think I mistakenly looked at the complexity for `HashSet`'s `fromList` which is O(n*min(W,n)). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, you're fine, except for a small error in your implementation[1]. As Jeffrey pointed out, `fromListWith` has *O(n log n)* complexity, which is quite good.

The potential issue you might face is appending, which could possibly be *O(n^2)* if all the keys were the same and you appended to the end of each list.  However, a little experiment shows

```
data Tree a = Branch (Tree a) (Tree a) | Leaf a
   deriving (Show)

ghci> M.fromListWith Branch [(1, Leaf 1), (1, Leaf 2), (1, Leaf 3)]
fromList [(1,Branch (Leaf 3) (Branch (Leaf 2) (Leaf 1)))]
```

that `fromListWith` gives the new element as the first argument to the combining function, so you will be prepending (which is *O(1)*) rather than appending (which is *O(n)*), so you're okay there.

[1]: You have forgotten to make singleton lists out of the values before passing to `M.fromListWith`.

Comment: Insertion and lookup is `O(logn)` in hash maps.

Comment: @Jefffrey, I think you are thinking of balanced trees.  Hash maps have O(n) formally, O(1) (amortized because of resizing) informally.

Comment: @Jefffrey OHHH a hashmap is just a Map that hashes the keys.  You're right.

Comment: The [package documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.5.1/docs/Data-HashMap-Strict.html) describes `insert` and `lookup` as being `O(log(n))` which would confirm the idea of some tree implementation.

Comment: So technically the algorithm is `O(n*log(n))`, not `O(n)`.

Comment: Hm, can you clarify the lack of singleton lists?

Comment: Never mind, I just realised :-) the example given doesn't but my actual code does.